# How can I save image data from Rails into json format for the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, exif

I am trying to look at creating a simple image save with paperclip or any other method that grabs the exif data from an image and saves a specific aspect of the data 'Keywords' into a json array into the db for an image upload.

I know there is a gem https://rubygems.org/gems/mini_exiftool.

Can this be easily implemented into a rails site?

Cheers

Comment: It's a Ruby gem, so it should be easy. If for some reason this should fail or you need to do some additional image processing anyway, like generating thumbnails, then use ImageMagick. I have used it for a stock photo site once and it can read exif data.

Comment: Okay, so it was easy enough saving data into the db from it as json formatted?

Comment: It's a few years back, so I don't remember details. I think there was a set of different fields (date when picture taken, settings of camera, some description texts...). You can either serialize a hash (maybe best, since the actual set of data can be quite different between cameras and some image programs allow manual manipulation) or have db columns for the fields you are interested in.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look into it! Thanks for the heads up! I will jump back on here if there are any issues!!

Answer (score 0):

I would surmise this has nothing to do with Paperclip, and more to do with how you're saving the data:

```
#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    @image.save
end

private

def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:image, :other, :info)
end
```

The trick will be to include the exif information in the params hash, so it can be saved to the database along-side the image